# zend form element add div after input field

Tags: zend-framework, zend-decorators

my zend form generates following code:

```
<dt id="register_username-label">
<label for="register_username" class="required">Membername*</label>
</dt>
<dd id="register_username-element">
<input type="text" name="register_username" id="register_username" value="" />
</dd>
```

but in some cases (handled in a separete decorator) i need to add some more html next to the input field (also in the dd tag). i have a instance of Zend_Form_Element_Text witch i could add some more decorators, but i don't know how to get this done :(

solution should look like this:

```
<dt id="register_username-label">
<label for="register_username" class="required">Membername*</label>
</dt>
<dd id="register_username-element">
<input type="text" name="register_username" id="register_username" value="" />
<div class="validate"><div class="validate-check"></div></div>
</dd>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add decorators to your form element in form file just as below

```
$form->addElement(
    'text',
    'register_username',
    array(
        'required' => false,
        'decorators' => array(
            array(
                'HtmlTag', array(
                    'tag'  => 'div',
                    'class' => 'validate'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

And more i would like to share with you one interesting [Link](http://devzone.zend.com/1240/decorators-with-zend_form/) to understand how zend form is basically works.

Please let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: thanks for your post. i don't get it. i'm in my class witch extends "Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract". In the render()-Function i'll get the rendered content of the element (looks like my first code). if i now get the element in the render function with $element = $this->getElement(), i'm able to add a new decorator. but that won't be used anymore, because the html for the element is already rendered. so what do i have to do, that i get the result i'm expecting? hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: yes are you doing correct way to create form. but as i describe in my answer you have to add decorator to your form element i think above will work for you. or please refer link carefully so you may i have clear idea to add html to element as you want.